# не ставить вторую точку в одном числе

Tags: python, pyqt6

пиши простой калькулятор в PyQt6 столкнулся с проблемой, калькулятор допускает постановку больше 1 точки в числе. подскажите что сделать чтобы можно было ставить только 1 точку в каждом числе. Код ниже:

```
       def command(self, key: str):
        ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
        right_btn = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "C", "AC", "."]
        if key != "=":
            if key.isdigit() or key in right_btn:
                if key.isdigit():
                    if self.__display == "0":
                            self.__display = key
                    else:
                        self.__display += key
                else:
                    if self.__display[-1] not in "+-*/.":
                            self.__display += key
                if key == "AC":
                    self.__display = "0"
                if key == ".":
                    for op in ops:
                        s = " ".join(self.__display.split(op))
                    s = s.split()
                    if "." not in s[-1]:
                        self.__display += key
                if key == "C":
                    if len(self.__display) > 2:
                        self.__display = self.__display[:-2]
                    else:
                        self.__display = "0"
        elif key == "=":
            print(self.__display)
            self.calculate()
```

Answer (score 3):

Как я понял, ваша переменная `self.__display` является строкой и предоставляет пользователю информацию о том, какое число он только что ввёл. Добавьте к своим условиям дополнительную проверку:

```
if key == ".":
    if "." not in self.__display:
        self.__display += key
```

Таким образом вы проверяете, а есть ли уже в строке точка. Если нет, то добавляем её в строку, иначе ничего не делаем (хотя здесь полёт фантазии, можно, например, подсвечивать на секунду кнопку точки на калькуляторе красным).

Если вы собрались в строке отображать сразу несколько чисел, разделённых знаками операций (+-*/), то тогда проверка будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
...
if key == ".":
    for op in ops:
        s = " ".join(self.__display.split(op))
    s = s.split()
    if "." not in s[-1]:
        self.__display += key
```

Comment: все равно добавляет(( Может скорее проверка должна быть если точка есть то тогда не нужно ее ставить. тогда возникает другой момент, мы првоеряем во всей строке self.__display. но после знака +-*/ точка вновь может ставиться

Comment: @Johhny но он не должен добавлять, перепроверьте свой код ещё раз. Может, что-то "конфликтует" с этой проверкой. Мне, например, не совсем понятно, для чего нужно это: `if key == "." in self.__display: self.__display -= key`. Я бы это удалил.
Что касается нескольких чисел (и, соответственно, точек) в строке - дополнил ответ.

Comment: исправил код с учетом ващей правки но почему то все равно хоть сколько точек добавляет(

Answer (score 3):

По хорошему, нужно делать синтаксический анализатор, поскольку дело не только в точках, можно и без точек сделать выражение некорректным, например `*2 // 3 --1++++`. Одним из простейших способов решения может быть проверка выражения с помощью регулярного выражения, например:

```
import re


def check_input(s, key):
    x = re.fullmatch(r'(?:-?\s*(?:\d+(?:\.(?:\d|$))?\d*\s*[+\-*/]?\s*|$))*', s + key)
    if x is None:
        print(f'Символ `{key}` недопустим, отклонён')
        return s
    print(f'Символ `{key}` корректный, добавлен')
    return s + key


input_string = '- 3 +2 //* .18.6.7 * -44.../ 55'
expr = ''
for key in input_string:
    expr = check_input(expr, key)
print(expr)
```

```
Символ `-` корректный, добавлен
Символ ` ` корректный, добавлен
Символ `3` корректный, добавлен
Символ ` ` корректный, добавлен
Символ `+` корректный, добавлен
Символ `2` корректный, добавлен
Символ ` ` корректный, добавлен
Символ `/` корректный, добавлен
Символ `/` недопустим, отклонён
Символ `*` недопустим, отклонён
Символ ` ` корректный, добавлен
Символ `.` недопустим, отклонён
Символ `1` корректный, добавлен
Символ `8` корректный, добавлен
Символ `.` корректный, добавлен
Символ `6` корректный, добавлен
Символ `.` недопустим, отклонён
Символ `7` корректный, добавлен
Символ ` ` корректный, добавлен
Символ `*` корректный, добавлен
Символ ` ` корректный, добавлен
Символ `-` корректный, добавлен
Символ `4` корректный, добавлен
Символ `4` корректный, добавлен
Символ `.` корректный, добавлен
Символ `.` недопустим, отклонён
Символ `.` недопустим, отклонён
Символ `/` недопустим, отклонён
Символ ` ` недопустим, отклонён
Символ `5` корректный, добавлен
Символ `5` корректный, добавлен
- 3 +2 / 18.67 * -44.55
```

Суть проверки - подаем на вход функции строку и символ, который был введен. Если `строка + символ` проходят проверку, то символ добавляем, иначе игнорируем.

В данном примере на вход поочередно (эмуляция посимвольного ввода пользователем) подается последовательность символов `'- 3 +2 //* .18.6.7 * -44.../ 55'`, в т.ч. недопустимых с точки зрения их места в выражении. Недопустимые символы игнорируются и на выходе - корректное выражение `- 3 +2 / 18.67 * -44.55`.